# How is the European integration process similar to the creation of the United States?

Tags: united-states, federalism, european-union, europe

What are the similarities and what are the major differences (economically, socially and culturally) between the current European integration process and the historical formation of the United States? Is the evolution from loose federation to a country in America a good indicator for future developments in Europe?

Comment: I can say how it is not similar. US constitution begins with "We the people". The project of EU constitution began with "His Majesty The King of the Belgians" and then described how the various government officials agreed on something. I think difference in approaches does not get more clear than that.

Comment: Also, the goal (perhaps unstated) of EU was to stop France and Germany from fighting each other. The goal of Unites States was to stop UK from rolling over each state piecemail.

Answer (score 6):

***Political Differences:***

- All the states of the United States have a common or very similar politician system where they elect the state-head of United States, the speakers for the congress, the governor, mayor and the member of district council, and others.
- The  Unites States Army is under the control of the president of United States, so there is only one army for the whole nation and not one by State.
- The inner political system differs between the members of the European Union, some are Constitutional Monarchies, others are Presidential Republics, others are Parliamentary Republics, but in all the members the governors or (province administrators) are elected by people.
- The Europeans Union members have their own Army which are under the control of the state-head or prime minister is some cases, so the European Union doesn't have only one army.

***Economic Differences and Similarities:***

- The United States economic activities are diverse, but there is a pattern, some States produce food, and others are more directed to the Industrial activities and Service.
- The Economic Geography in the European Union isn't uniform as we have seen since 2007 ~ 2008 with the economical crisis, most of economist use to say that the north of the EU is highly industrial developed with many High Technology Design Industries and Manufacture Industries, but the South is more directed to the Agriculture, Industrial Production of food, Tourism and other Services.

***Cultural Differences:***

- All the states of United States of America have the same language.
- The languages of the European Union are very diverse, Spanish, English, French, Italian, Greek, and others.

***Religious Differences:***

- There are several religions in United States, protestantism, evangelism, catholicism, and others, but they are very homogeneous distributed along all in United States ( I mean you can't say all Maryland's citizens are Christians but Massachusetts's citizens are all catholic, the difference isn't so high ).
- The religions in the Europe Union's members aren't so uniformly distributed, which increases the cultural differences between the Union members ( For example Spanish, Italian, Austrian, Belgium and Portuguese citizens are mostly catholic, but Germans, Dutches are protestant ).

Comment: This is a very thorough answer, but I don't think it actually addresses the question.  The question isn't so much "What is the difference currently?" as "Can parallels be drawn between the *process*?"

Comment: You are looking at the *current* situation of politics, economics an culture in the united states, but the question was about the *historic* formation of the united states. How do these points look when you compare how they were in the US **in the 18th century**?